# PowerManager.userActivity() does not turn the display on

Tags: android, powermanager

I have a count-down timer activity and want to turn the display on when the timer is done. I tried

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
pm.userActivity(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), false);
```

but nothing happens, no error reported, display remains off or dimmed. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: sorry but i cant understand u.. please explain it a bit more.

Comment: I want to turn screen on, but it just does not work this way.